Automator 'Ask for Finder Items' variable issue
This simple script doesn't seem to work as expected in the Automator app.
The result shows the second variable where the first should be, and the second variable is blank. Any idea why?
ITEM="$1"   
FOLDER="$2"

# Debug
echo "Link: $ITEM"
echo "Folder: $FOLDER"



Welcome to Ask Different. The "Ask for Finder items" action, when muiltiple item selection is disabled, returns one value, namely the folder you've selected in the file picker window, which is then passed to the script as $1 so it seems it works correctly. Which values would you expect for ITEM and FOLDER when you select the Desktop folder? Also, note that you can remove the first line (#!/bin/bash) of your script, because you already specify the shell as /bin/bash.

Thanks for the info. I had misunderstood how this works.

I thought the 'Ask for Text' and 'Ask for Finder Items' would result in two variables, $1 and $2 respectively. Turns out I needed to also use 'Set Value of Variable' and 'Get Value of Variable' to achieve this.

Also, looking at the action description will tell you what the expected input and output items are.  For example, if the result from Ask for Text is a valid (POSIX) file path, Ask for Finder Items will accept it and pass it on.
